# Chern forms and tensor products

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, holomorphic-bundles

Let $E\to X$ be a rank $r$ holomorphic vector bundle over a Kahler manifold and let $L\to X$ be a holomorphic line bundle. The following relation between Chern classes is (well) known:
$$c_2(E\otimes L)=c_2(E)+(r-1)c_1(E)c_1(L)+\binom{r}{2}c_1(L)^2.$$
Assume now that $E,L$ are endowed with Hermitian metrics $h_E,h_L$. Does the above relation holds at the level of differential forms ? In other terms do we have the following identity of **Chern forms**
$$c_2(E\otimes L,h_E\otimes h_L)=c_2(E,h_E)+(r-1)c_1(E,h_E)c_1(L,h_L)+\binom{r}{2}c_1(L,h_L)^2?$$

Comment: What have you tried, and where is the issue?

Comment: @TedShifrin the proof I saw was using cohomological identities. I wonder whether there is a proof that works for forms

Comment: This doesn’t answer my question. Write down the curvature form of the tensor product.

Comment: You generally are not very responsive to comments/suggestions, I see. Have you tried to write down what the connection and curvature forms of the tensor product are?

Comment: @TedShifrin yes I have and I answered my question using the formula $c_2=Tr(\Omega)^2/2-Tr(\Omega^2)/2$. I just havent written down the answer yet

Comment: Ah, good. I had two different solutions, both of which will yield the result for all $c_j$.

Comment: Interesting, which ones?

Comment: Either using the characteristic polynomial (which defines the Chern forms) or using the explicit summation formula for the Chern forms.